# Как записать новое своиство к обьекту с нужным именем?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть обьект Cart

```
let Cart = new Object();
Cart.sum = 0;
```

И есть функции

```
//Кнопка для добавления в (корзину) или удаление из (корзины)
function addToCartBtn(btn) {
  let card = btn.closest(".card");

  let product = {
    id: card.dataset.id,
    urlImage: card.querySelector(".card-img").getAttribute("src"),
    name: card.querySelector(".card-name").textContent,
    price: card.querySelector(".card-price").textContent,
    date: card.querySelector(".card-date").textContent,
  };

  if (!btn.classList.contains("added")) {
    addToCart(btn, product);
  } else {
    removeToCart(btn);
  }
}

//Функция для добавления в корзину
function addToCart(btn, product) {
  btn.textContent = "✓ добавлено";
  btn.classList.add("added");

  Cart.game = product;
  console.log(Cart);
}

//Функция для удаления из корзины
function removeToCart(btn) {
  btn.classList.remove("added");
  btn.textContent = "в корзину";

  //Тут удаляется
}
```

Хотелось чтобы в обьект добавился с названием товара и удалялся по его имени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cart[`${name}`] = value;
```

Нужно косые кавычки но тут они не вставляются

Хотел закрыть вопрос

Comment: Всё тут ставится, при желании...)

Comment: `Cart[\`${name}\`]` --- в целом смысла в такой записи нет.... можно просто `Cart[name]`